# AWS S3: Receiving access denied with full control during upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

I am implementing uploading of file and I have following code:

```
params = {
 Bucket: 'mybuck'
};
AWS.getBucketAcl(params, function(err, data) {
 if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else console.log(data);      
});

params = {
 Key: 'testfile',
 Bucket: 'mybuck',
 Body: 'testcontent',
};
AWS.upload(params, (err, data) => {
 if (err) console.log(err);
   else console.log(key);
});
```

The First request is returning "Permission: Full Controll" and the second one is giving me AccessDenied error:

```
> message: 'Access Denied', 
> code: 'AccessDenied',
> region: null,
> time: 2018-12-12T08:19:39.534Z
> requestId: '.....'
> extendedRequestId: '.....'
> cfId: undefined
> statusCode: 403
```

Does anyone know where is the issue? Thanks!

EDIT1:
Whole output for the ACL query is:

```
{ Owner: { ID: '<censored>' },Grants: [ { Grantee: [Object], Permission: 'FULL_CONTROL' } ] }
```

Comment: Seems there are missing permissions for the user. Can you post the IAM Policy document for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was in the AWS IAM policy. I had full control, but I didnt have permission for manipulating with objects. Adding those permission solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing to add `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`.

```
//S3 configuraton
var s3 = new aws.S3({ 
    accessKeyId: '', 
    secretAccessKey: ''
}); 

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {

});
```

Comment: I have aws.S3 configured before my code snippet. That is why, I am able to get my permissions. There are based on the access key and secret. So in my case, I am using keys with full access controll.

Comment: Whole output for the ACL query is: `{ Owner: { ID: '<censored>' },Grants: [ { Grantee: [Object], Permission: 'FULL_CONTROL' } ] }`

Comment: there is missing your IAM creation it. Could you share your policy document file?

Comment: The issue was in the AWS IAM policy. This account doesnt had permission to manipulate with objects.